# Process messages pushed through Kafka

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I haven't used Kafka before and wanted to know if messages are published through Kafka what are the possible ways to capture that info?

Is Kafka only way to receive that info via "Consumers" or can Rest APIs be also used here?
Haven't used Kafka before and while reading up I did find that Kafka needs ZooKeeper running too.

I don't need to publish info just process data received from Kafka publisher.
Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is a distributed streaming platform that allows you to process streams of records in near real-time.

Producers publish records/messages to Topics in the cluster.

Consumers subscribe to Topics and process those messages as they are available.

The Kafka docs are an excellent place to get up to speed on the core concepts: https://kafka.apache.org/intro

Answer (score 0):

> Is Kafka only way to receive that info via "Consumers" or can Rest APIs be also used here?

Kafka has its own TCP based protocol, not a native HTTP client (assuming that's what you actually mean by REST)

Consumers are the only way to get and subsequently process data, however plenty of external tooling exists to make it so you don't have to write really any code if you don't want to in order to work on that data